# Should version in package.json follow semver always?

Tags: angular, package.json, semantic-versioning

I need to modify the `package.json` of my angular app depending on custom build versioning format. Is it compulsory to follow semver in version and is there any scenario where using a custom version format might result into error in angular app.

Comment: Note that `npm install` works fine with custom version format.

Answer (score 1):

No its not compulsory, however you would like to do it since it gives you newer compatible code.

As long as you do not change the major version number, there should not be any errors.

As you mentioned using customer version format works fine!

> Not every module follows Semantic Versioning. A module might use
>   three-part version number, but increment them as they like. The safest
>   way is to check the module documentation

However there's a catch

> Let's say you are using version 1.3.4 of a library with a tilde (~) as your dependency. The library is well maintained and advances quickly. Today the latest version is actually 1.5.1. Then a mission critical bug is discovered that affects every version to date. The bug gets proper treatment and is soon fixed in version 1.5.2. Now it is likely that there will be no tailored bug fix patch release 1.3.5 for your version and you end up not getting that bug fix

Comment: excellent article https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/

Comment: To make things reproducible you need to replace version number ranges with exact versions.

To augment this: even if you specify exact versions in YOUR package.json, it doesn't imply a reproducible build, since your dependencies themselves usually have looser specifications, e.g. caret. In this case, a fresh install will pick up a newer version as the dependency of your dependency, which may still break things.

Comment: The cited npm-shrinkwrap solves it by recursing over the dependency tree and specifying the exact version in a JSON tree in your top-level npm-shrinkwrap.json, i.e. it does NOT modify package.json files in your node_modules directory. This still isn't 100% guarantee of reproducibility, because new code might arrive under the same patch version number. Tools such as https://www.npmjs.com/packa... exist to give better guarantees, or one may have in-house source control for dependencies.